# Outlook missing sent items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365, cached-exchange-mode

We've got a few users that are experiencing intermittent issues with Outlook 2013 in Cached Mode.

Some messages sent during a span of time are missing (for example a two hour window).  The user sends a message (the original message that was replied to states as such).  But the message doesn't appear in the sent items, and the recipient doesn't receive the message.  A message trace through Exchange Online doesn't show anything either.

It doesn't appear to occur when Outlook isn't using cached mode.  We use Webroot SecureAnywhere for AV, but they haven't been able to find an issue with their software. The user is on Outlook 2013 and it's up-to-date.

It appears that this user on another site is having a similar problem:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Groupware/Outlook/Q_28513868.html

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: do the machines have an AV? I've had AV's steal messages from folders never to be seen again before.

Comment: We do use SecureAnywhere end point protection.  I've added an exclusion for the outlook.exe, are there any other processes that need to be considered?